# Passing an object from one page to another in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

On page1.aspx I have a button tied to a buttonOnClick event in my server side. 
Clicking the button runs buttonOnClick method which generates an object (local to buttonOnclick method) with data I would like to use in the construction of a new page.

Basically, I want to open a new (different) page (page2.aspx) in a new tab, but as this page loads, I want it to render based on the contents of the object generated during buttonOnClick.

How one might go about this properly? Up until now I have been passing URL arguments to the new popup (page2.aspx) and I have it build the object, but I would rather do this properly and generate it buttonOnclick and then load page2.aspx in a popup based on what is the object built in the buttonOnclick method.

Comment: Page1.aspx and page2.aspx are both running on the same server. (They're even in the same folder :-) )

Comment: Matt, edit your question with additional information. Don't add comments.

Comment: Also, a small point: this has nothing at all to do with IIS. Also, it's "ASP.NET", not "ASP". There are still people who are forced to create and maintain actual ASP pages. We call that "Classic ASP" just to make them feel bad about themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the object in your Session on the first page and then retrieve it on your second page.

On first page:

```
Session["myobject"] = myObject;
```

On second page:

```
MyObject object = (MyObject) Session["myobject"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to store the object in the user's Session.

```
Session["myObject"] = myObject;
```

To get it out, you will need to cast it back to the type of MyObject, since the Session cache is simply a hashtable of objects.

```
if (Session["myObject"] != null)
{
  MyObject myobj = (MyObject)Session["myObject"];
}
```

You can access it from both pages this way.  Generally, if multiple pages are going to be accessing the same object in Session, I usually store the name of the session key in a centralized location so that it only has to be updated once should you ever decide to change it.  Usually I add a resource file to my application and put it in the Properties folder, so I can use it this way:

```
string key = WebApplication1.Properties.MyObjectSessionKey;
Session[key] = myObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use session state or store the object in a database and pass the id to the second page. The object will need to be serializable for this.