# send object from page to page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how can i send object from page to page in asp.net?

Comment: What kind of object?  A string?  Is it serializable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an object from one page to another in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215434/passing-an-object-from-one-page-to-another-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using a Session variable? You can save your object to a session varible and then retrieve it from the called page.

Here's an example:

**Set from one page**
Session["myobject"] = MyObject;

**Retrieve from another**
MyObject o = Session["myobject"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Session` to store a user-specific object between pages, or send data via a form `GET` or `POST`.  There is also `PreviousPage` for a cross-page postback.

Answer (score 0):

- Session
- Database
- Context Cache
- XML/Text File
- Post/Get
- Azure
- Querystring
- Pure willpower ;)